# What does "link#1" mean?

Tags: openbsd, route

```
netstat -rn
Routing tables
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags    Refs      Use    Mtu  Interface
default            75.126.68.49       UGS         7     1203      -   pcn0
1.2.3.3/29    link#1             UC          1        0      -   pcn0
...
```

**My question**: What does "link#1" mean? The OS is OpenBSD.

Answer (score 2):

Other responses have described what *kind* of address `link#N` is. To find out what specific interface (say) `link#20` refers to, use `ifconfig -v` and look for `index NNN` at the end of the first line for each interface:

```
$ ifconfig -v
en9: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 index 20
```

Answer (score 1):

There is some good info over at this question, for OSX (which is basically FreeBSD): https://superuser.com/questions/1067732/whats-the-meaning-of-link4-in-macs-route-table

The essence of it is that `link#N` entries indicate no real routing is done. Those addresses are on the local network segment, and don't need to be routed — they are just connected by ethernet.

There is still a somewhat open question regarding the ordering of `link#1`, `link#2`, ...
I don't have a certain answer, but they seem to refer to your interfaces in the same order that `ifconfig` outputs them.

How exactly this ordering is determined I'm less sure, though.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/network-routing.html

> The designation link#1 refers to the first Ethernet card in the
>   machine.

But there is still the question: what does the "first Ethernet card" mean? How to determine which one is it when we have multiple ethernet cards with different chipsets? :)

Comment: It appears that if you run `ifconfig`, they will output in the order the links are numbered.