# What does the "first Ethernet card" mean in the BSD world?

Tags: networking, freebsd, ethernet

https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/network-routing.html

```
The designation link#1 refers to the first Ethernet card in the machine.
```

**Question:** what does the "first Ethernet card" mean? How to determine which one is it when we have multiple ethernet cards with different chipsets? :)

Related: [What does "link#1" mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110642/what-does-link1-mean)

Answer (score 2):

Ethernet cards will be ordered and named using two criteria(not only ethernet cards):

- The manufacturer, will give you the name(igb, dc, em, de) that will be the same as the module.
- With the PCI Nuber from the lowest to the highest, you will have the interface numbers starting with zero.

You can list all pci devices using the `pciconf -l` command, and check out what are the ID´s and why they are following a specific order.

If you take a look at the links below, you will find that there are many ways to renumber Ethernet interfaces, and the best way(less effort) of doing it is remaping pci ids on your Bios configuration.

**Related Links:**

- pciconf [manpages](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pciconf&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html)
- device.hints configuration file [manpages](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=device.hints%285%29&sektion=)
- The FreeBSD Handbook - [Setting up Interface Cards](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/config-network-setup.html)
- FreeBSD Forums - [Re-numbering network interfaces](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/re-numbering-network-interfaces.27100/)